# Using [T1]{fontenc} with Czech language looks strange

Tags: languages, font-encodings

Using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is important e.g. if you write something in czech "je důležitý, když chceš napsat něco v češtině", but letters looks somehow strange - is it possible? I mean in word "daného" the letter "é" looks bigger than others ... Does anybody know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Make a small complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem

Comment: Ehm, the phrase "je důležitý, když chceš napsat něco v češtině" does not seem to contain the letter "é". Anyway, I don't see this problem.  Maybe it is a font you are using? As Ulrike suggests, providing a complete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\begin{document}
je důležitý, když chceš napsat něco v češtině", \\
but letters looks somehow strange - is it
\end{document}
```

which letters are wrong?

[image]

Comment: None. Everything is fine.